# Find all adjacent combinations

Tags: r, vector, combinations, element

I have a vector:

```
data <- c("ta", "tb", "tc", "tk", "tf")
```

How do I transform this vector to a list in which each possible combination of n (where n ranges from 2 to length(data)-1) adjacent elements is included? The list should look as follows (each row represents a list element):

```
"ta", "tb"
"tb", "tc"
"tc", "tk"
"tk", "tf"
"ta", "tb", "tc"
"tb", "tc", "tk"
"tc", "tk", "tf"
"ta", "tb", "tc", "tk"
"tb", "tc", "tk", "tf"
```

I need to perform this operation many times so speed is important. Thanks!

Comment: What is your typical `length(data)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit: New function

```
myFun <- function(Data) {
  A <- lapply(2:(length(Data)-1L), sequence)
  B <- lapply(rev(lengths(A))-1L, function(x) c(0, sequence(x)))
  unlist(lapply(seq_along(A), function(x) {
    lapply(B[[x]], function(y) Data[A[[x]]+y])
  }), recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)
}
```

Usage:

```
myFun(data)
```

---

#### Original Function

Here is a solution using `rollapply` from "zoo":

```
myFun <- function(Data, singles = FALSE) {
  require(zoo)
  x <- 2:(length(Data)-1)
  out <- lapply(x, function(y) rollapply(Data, FUN = c, width = y))
  if (isTRUE(singles)) {
    out <- unlist(lapply(out, function(y) split(y, sequence(nrow(y)))),
                  recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)
  }
  out
}
```

If you want to split up the output of the above by row (each item in a new list item) use the `singles = TRUE` argument:

```
myFun(data, singles = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "ta" "tb"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "tb" "tc"
# 
#######
# SNIP
#######
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] "ta" "tb" "tc" "tk"
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] "tb" "tc" "tk" "tf"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
adj.poss <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  stopifnot(n > 2L)
  idx <- expand.grid(start = 1L:n, len = 2L:(n-1L))
  idx$end <- idx$start + idx$len - 1L
  idx <- idx[idx$end <= n, ]
  Map(function(start, end) x[start:end], idx$start, idx$end)
}
```

where `adj.poss(data)` gives your expected output, in the exact same order as you specified.

Comment: I went with foldel's answer. For my data (typical length < 10) it was the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `data.table`'s `vecseq` function. Basically, `vecseq(x, y, clamp)` takes for each number in x, the value of y from corresponding index and constructs the sequence x:(x+len). That is, `vecseq(c(1L, 4L), c(2L, 6L), 5L)` constructs the sequence `c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L)`. The `clamp` argument is just an argument that *should* be >= length of the answer. If you don't know, you can just give a relatively big number.

The idea is to generate the indices using `vecseq` and then split to get a list accordingly. I hope by running the code below step by step, things should be obvious (with a little effort :)).

```
data <- c("ta", "tb", "tc", "tk", "tf")
require(data.table)
ff <- data.table:::vecseq
my_fun <- function(data) {
    xmin = 2L
    xmax = length(data)-1L
    len = xmax-xmin+1L
    tot = sum(xmax:xmin)

    t1 = ff(rep(1L, len), xmax:xmin, tot)
    t2 = rep.int(xmin:xmax, xmax:xmin)
    idx = ff(t1,t2,sum(t2))
    dt = data.table(x=data[idx], id=rep.int(seq_along(t2), t2))
    setattr(dt, 'sorted', 'id')
    dt[J(seq_along(t2)), list(list(x))]$V1
}
```

This seems quite fast and is in par with @flodel's (excellent) answer. When the length of the data hits around 250, the difference is around 0.2 seconds (with this solution being faster). So, there's not much difference.